# android custom view onmeasure TextView

Tags: java, android

I tried to do custom component. I extended View class and do some TextView in method override onMeasure?  I've seen couple tutorials, but each one is a little been different. Sometimes they call super.onMeasure at the end, sometimes they use setMeasuredDimension and didn't call it. Where is a difference image and textview in onMeasure size ?

my cod for onmeasure ImageView for SquareImageView

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
       super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
       super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
       setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
       //Snap to width
   }
}
```

How can I set dynamic height in `TextView`?

```
    <com.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Comment: Please split into two questions!

Answer (score 1):

Edit

```
 super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
```

To

```
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
```

Answer (score 0):

This's a ImageView or TextView?

When you create a Object in your fragment or activity, you can put width, weight and height as you want.

Something like that:

```
SquareImageView squareImageView = findViewById(R.id.picture);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
squareImageView.setLayaoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: But if you need the width in xml, the width can't be dinamic. You can put the width in xml as match_parent (for example) and you change it in code.